# What's the total generic pointer type?

Tags: c++, c

I need a place to hold object and function pointers interchangeably. Is using union of a `void *` and a `void (*)(void)` a portable solution?

```
union GenericPtr {
    void *obj_ptr;
    void (*fun_ptr)(void);
};

extern int *x, fn(void);
union GenericPtr ptr1, ptr2;
ptr1.obj_ptr = (void *) x;
ptr2.fun_ptr = (void (*)(void)) fn;
```

Comment: You can just use pointer to `void`, it is not clear why would you need a union here. Strictly speaking, pointer to function does not necessary have the same size as pointer to void, but that would be relevant only on some exotic platforms.

Comment: "I need a place to hold object and function pointers interchangeably" - sounds like a terrifying design constraint.

Comment: @VTT I thought `void *` can be used as a function pointer only when compiled for POSIX-compliant machines (eg `dlsym` function). Is this incorrect?

Comment: I can't name any platform where pointer to function has different size...

Comment: On the other hand, pointer to member function definitely has a size != sizeof(void*), even on common platforms.

Comment: Also write *either* C *or* C++. It is likely you will write something that has a different meaning if you try to write both at once. `union`s particularly have different rules

Comment: @lubgr one example: an interpreter where functions and variables share the same namespace. Maybe not the best way to implement it, but still...

Comment: `std::variant`? `std::any`?

Comment: @VTT very easy. For example any MSDOS C compiler.

Comment: microcontrollers also often have different function pointer and data pointer size

Comment: In any case, the question is *bad*. There are two answers: "yes", and "no", for C and C++ respectively :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Why no for C++?

Comment: @PSkocik Because it cannot point to "everything"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala MSDOS certainly sounds like an exotic platform in 2019...

Comment: Instead of asking how to do this overly specific and questionable thing, try posting a question about the problem you are trying to solve, your constraints, and why you consider this a solution. Our answers can only be as good as the information you share with us, which is very little in this case.

Comment: @VTT Are you happier with [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org/), or lots of microcontrollers? Anyway, the Itanium had such, though I think Windows at least hid it behind selectors. As they say, "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection, except for the problem of too many layers of indirection."

Comment: Most probably there is an XY problem here. Please clarify, what are you trying to achieve on a higher level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is using union of a `void *` and a `void (*)(void)` a portable solution?

It works for pointing to either objects, or functions that are not non-static member functions. Note that you might want to use `std::variant` instead to save a lot of boiler plate code that you would need with this union.

---

This indeed does leave out pointers to members, which aren't strictly "pointers", but are still called "pointers" in general. Since there are as many different types of these as there are classes, a union cannot be used to point to all of them.

A pointer generic enough to point to members as well can be achieved with additional indirection: A `void*` pointer to a block of memory that contains a pointer of whatever type is necessary. There is a type for this in standard library: `std::any` (not limited to holding any pointer, but indeed an object of any type, including any pointer).

Comment: alternatively use [Boost.Variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html)